# How to copy chrome bookmarks from different user profiles on a single desktop to another network location

Tags: powershell, batch-file, copy, windows-scripting

I have to make a network backup of a shared drive.

I'm using a simple [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) command for most of the part, but now I have to copy all of the `Bookmarks` files located in `\\test-pc\c$\-multipleUsers-\App data\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks` to a single network location.

My working code to copy all user profiles user data is :

```
xcopy /I /Y /Exclude:excluded.txt  \\%1\c%\Users\*.* "\\backup\%1\Profiles"
```

I've excluded the `Appdata` directory in my code because of all of the junk in there, but now I need just a specific file from each users profile location, *the `Bookmarks` file from  `UserProfile\App data\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`*, but without knowing the users profile folder name. *(I want it do guess it automatically)*

Comment: Your code has not attempted the task you require of it, and as such your question is a code request. Code requests are off topic on this site, as we help to fix a specific issue you've identified and explained with your script. That issue cannot be, I don't know how to do it, which does not show us what you've researched, tried, or failed to correctly implement. Please use the search facility, locate some similar questions and take the answers to those as a basis for writing your own solution. If that solution then fails, you may have enough information to create an on topic question here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'chrome://bookmarks/'. In options on top right, you will see option to Import and Export bookmarks. Export from 1 location and import to another.